# select record with varios date/time criteria and periodicity(LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a several fields in my class: `RecurrenceStart, RecurrenceEnd, Periodicity, RecurrenceType, WeekDays, DayNumber, WeekOfMonth`. 
For example, record in a DB with the following values:

```
Name = Event1
DateTimeStart = 2012-02-23 22:00:00.000 
DateTimeEnd = 2012-12-31 23:30:00.000
Periodicity = 2 
RecurrenceType = 1
WeekDays =  62
DayNumber = 1
WeekOfMonth = 1
```

It's mean that `Event1` will go every 2 weeks on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday from 22:00 to 23:30 and from 23 February to 31 December.

Another example:

```
Name = Event1
DateTimeStart = 2012-02-23 22:00:00.000 
DateTimeEnd = 2012-12-31 23:30:00.000
Periodicity = 2 
ReccurenceType = 2
WeekDays =  16
DayNumber = 25
WeekOfMonth = 0
```

It's mean that `Event1` will go 25 day of every 2 months from 22:00 to 23:30 and from 23 February to 31 December.
This is enums:

```
    [Flags, Serializable,]
    public enum WeekDays {
        Sunday = 1,
        Monday = 2,
        Tuesday = 4,
        Wednesday = 8,
        Thursday = 16,
        Friday = 32,
        Saturday = 64,
        WeekendDays = Sunday | Saturday,
        WorkDays = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday,
        EveryDay = WeekendDays | WorkDays
    }

    public enum WeekOfMonth {
        None = 0,
        First = 1,
        Second = 2,
        Third = 3,
        Fourth = 4,
        Last = 5
    }

    public enum RecurrenceType {
        Daily = 0,
        Weekly = 1,
        Monthly = 2,
        Yearly = 3,
        Minutely = 4,
        Hourly = 5,
    }
```

This is my query:

```
Database.BaseEvents.Where(e =>
                          e.RecurrenceStart.Value.Date <= today &&
                          e.RecurrenceEnd.Value.Date >= today
                          ).ToList();
```

This query check only start and end dates of event. How to build query that will be checks all another fields or checks another fields with helper method( but I need to perfomance).

Can you help me with this task?

**PS.** for first example my query will return `Event1` every day from 2012-02-23 to 2012-12-31. But `Event1` should return only is today 2012-02-23 - 2012-03-26. Then skip one weeks. Therefore, next dates when this event will return: from 2012-03-05 to 2012-11-05. then skip week again.... and so on.

Thanks and sorry for my english.